Callback query doesn't works in node th bot
I created inline menu buttons, first 3 should initialize user to dialog with admin, and last 2 opens website. But the first buttons doesn't work.
// Add new function for follow-up message – **here begins my trouble**
function sendFollowUpMessage(chatId) {
    const followUpKeyboard = {
        inline_keyboard: [
            [{ text: ' first inline', callback_data: 'support_1' }],
            [{ text: ' second inline', callback_data: 'support_2' }],
            [{ text: ' third inline', callback_data: 'support_3' }],
            [{ text: ' fourth inline', url: 'https://site.ru/' }],
            [{ text: ' fifth inline', url: 'https://site.ru/' }]
        ]
    };

    bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'What about website or support?', {
        reply_markup: followUpKeyboard
    });
}

// Add callback query handler for support buttons
bot.on('callback_query', (query) => {
    const chatId = query.message.chat.id;
    
    if (query.data.startsWith('support_')) {
        usersInSupportChat.add(chatId);
        bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'Connected to support.');
        // Send notification to admin
        bot.sendMessage(admin-id, `User ${query.from.username || query.from.first_name} (${chatId}) started support chat`);
        
        // Answer callback query
        bot.answerCallbackQuery(query.id);
    }
});

// Variable to track users in support chat mode
let usersInSupportChat = new Set();

Tried to add await, but nothing changed. While clicked on first three buttons is result with long connection in Telegram

What is TG or “th”? Please be explicit — it helps to get your question answered quicker. Also, why supply such giant example? Does it matter what happens if the first call doesn’t work? Please simplify the example to bare minimum that does not work, and repost it here. Large amount of unrelated to the issue code adds cognitive load to anyone attempting to help you for no good reason.

@kigster Thank you for reply! Simplified the code, but I thought, thr shole code will br needed. TG is Telegram (buttons to send post to admin while clicking is long loading and notiing any more).
